# Scrape a table to get specific data out

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape both the 'settle' columns in conjunction with the base month and what respective table they are from (from this url: https://www.asxenergy.com.au/futures_nz/A)

I am able to run an html parser, but as soon as I attempt to run something similar to this:

```
 table1 = soup.find(‘table’)
 table1
```

it just comes back with nothing being there. I assume I'm making an error regarding the table tag. Would really appreciate some help!

Ideally I would like to be able to get the data from this table and then store it in a dataframe.

Comment: If you have not already done so, you should do "View Source" on that page.  The page you download contains almost no HTML at all.  Everything you see is built dynamically with Javascript.  You would need to use a real browser, using something like Selenium, to extract data.  You might check to see if there isn't an API you can use to get that more intelligently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read tables to panda's DataFrames you can use next example (as @TimRobers said, the data is loaded with JavaScript from different URL):

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.asxenergy.com.au/futures_nz/dataset"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")


for table in soup.select("table:not(:has(table))"):
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
    df["TITLE"] = table.find_previous("h2").get_text(strip=True)
    print(df)
    print("-" * 160)
```

Prints:

```
  Base Month Bid Size Bid Ask Ask Size    High     Low    Last    +/- Vol OpenInt OpenInt +/-  Settle    TITLE
0   Aug 2022        -   -   -        -   54.00   52.85   54.00  +1.45  30    1610           -   52.55  Otahuhu
1   Sep 2022        -   -   -        -   69.00   66.00   66.00  +1.00  97    1624           -   65.00  Otahuhu
2   Oct 2022        -   -   -        -   84.10   81.75   81.75  +0.30  62    1585           -   81.45  Otahuhu
3   Nov 2022        -   -   -        -  104.00  100.45  100.45  +0.40  62    1192           -  100.05  Otahuhu
4   Dec 2022        -   -   -        -   87.25   84.70   84.70  +0.35  32     952           -   84.35  Otahuhu
5   Jan 2023        -   -   -        -  119.10  118.10  118.20  +0.55  58     524           -  117.65  Otahuhu
6   Feb 2023        -   -   -        -       -       -       -      -   -       3           -  175.25  Otahuhu
7   Mar 2023        -   -   -        -       -       -       -      -   -       -           -  184.20  Otahuhu
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Base Quarter Bid Size Bid Ask Ask Size    High     Low    Last    +/-  Vol  OpenInt OpenInt +/-  Settle    TITLE
0       Q3 2022        -   -   -        -   75.30   73.15   73.65  -0.65   31     3679           -   74.30  Otahuhu
1       Q4 2022        -   -   -        -   91.60   87.60   88.50      -   65     4109           -   88.50  Otahuhu
2       Q1 2023        -   -   -        -  163.25  158.50  158.50      -  123     3401           -  158.50  Otahuhu
3       Q2 2023        -   -   -        -       -       -       -      -    -     2403           -  214.00  Otahuhu
4       Q3 2023        -   -   -        -  216.00  216.00  216.00      -   30     2438           -  216.00  Otahuhu
5       Q4 2023        -   -   -        -  143.55  142.00  143.55      -   60     3357           -  143.55  Otahuhu
6       Q1 2024        -   -   -        -       -       -       -      -    -     3093           -  159.00  Otahuhu
7       Q2 2024        -   -   -        -  197.00  197.00  197.00      -   30     2082           -  197.00  Otahuhu
8       Q3 2024        -   -   -        -       -       -       -      -    -     2091           -  197.50  Otahuhu
9       Q4 2024        -   -   -        -  145.95  143.00  145.95      -   40     2649           -  145.95  Otahuhu
10      Q1 2025        -   -   -        -  151.00  150.50  150.70  -0.30   46     1838           -  151.00  Otahuhu
11      Q2 2025        -   -   -        -  178.00  175.20  176.00      -   92     1619           -  176.00  Otahuhu
12      Q3 2025        -   -   -        -  178.00  175.20  176.00      -   92     1316           -  176.00  Otahuhu
13      Q4 2025        -   -   -        -  128.45  125.00  125.50      -  100     1845           -  125.50  Otahuhu
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```